# Docker compose with .NET Core, SQL Server, Elasticsearch, and cerebro services

Tags: c#, docker, elasticsearch, .net-core, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a number of services using a docker-compose file.
First of all let's say that Docker, version 20.10.3, is running on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.3.

This is the docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  projmssql:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
    container_name: proj-core-sqlserver
    environment:
        SA_PASSWORD: "mypassword"
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
      - "1401:1433"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./data-mssql
        target: /var/opt/mssql/data
      - type : bind
        source: ./log-mssql
        target: /var/opt/mssql/log
    restart: always
  projelastic:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.1
    container_name: proj-core-elastic
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=proj-docker-cluster
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
      - path.repo=/usr/share/elasticsearch/backup
      - path.logs=/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./data-es01
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - type : bind
        source: ./_backup-es01
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/backup
      - type : bind
        source: ./logs-es01
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs
    ports:
      - 9220:9200
      - 9320:9300
  projcerebro:
    image: lmenezes/cerebro
    container_name: proj-core-cerebro
    ports:
      - "9020:9000"
    command:
      - -Dhosts.0.host=http://projelastic:9200
  projapi:
    image: proj/projcoreapp 
    depends_on:
       - projmssql
    container_name: proj-core-api
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    restart: always
    #Specify Environment Variables for the Api Service
    environment: 
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Docker
```

The projApi service comes from my local image (proj/projcoreapp) built with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish proj.api.net -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Proj.Api.dll"]
```

In my .net core app I have a dedicated appsettings.Docker.json file

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Elasticsearch": {
    "Server": "http://projelastic:9200",
    "DebugMode": true,
    "UpdateMapping": false
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DatabaseConnection": "Server=projmssql;Database=PROJ-NET;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=mypassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
  }
}
```

The `.csproj` of the API .net core project

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile></DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI" Version="5.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.9.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.10.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\domain.net\Domain.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The `.csproj` of the Domain library

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Entities\Organisation.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Entities\OrganisationTeam.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Entities\OrganisationTeamRole.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Elasticsearch.Net" Version="7.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="NEST" Version="7.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Utilities\" />
    <Folder Include="ViewModels\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\filter.net\Filter.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The `.csproj` of the Filter library

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Elasticsearch.Net" Version="7.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="GeoJSON.Net" Version="1.2.19" />
    <PackageReference Include="NEST" Version="7.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Entities\" />
    <Folder Include="Helpers\" />
    <Folder Include="ViewModelMapper\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

In my .net core startup I have the following configuration

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ProjdbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection"))
            );
            services.AddScoped<IProjUserService, ProjUserService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IProjEntitiesService>(s =>
                new ProjEntitiesService
                (
                    Configuration.GetValue<string>("Elasticsearch:Server"),
                    Configuration.GetValue<bool>("Elasticsearch:DebugMode"),
                    Configuration.GetValue<bool>("Elasticsearch:UpdateMapping")
                ));

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
```

Now let's talk about the issue:
once I run the docker-compose file, all the services run correctly and from the host I can interact with all of them. The API service is able to connect internally to the database but once I run some APIs to interact with the elasticsearch service I get the following error:

```
Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException: The information requested is unavailable on the current platform.
 ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: The information requested is unavailable on the current platform.
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.StringParsingHelpers.ParseActiveTcpConnectionsFromFiles(String tcp4ConnectionsFile, String tcp6ConnectionsFile)
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.LinuxIPGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections()
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Diagnostics.TcpStats.GetStates()
   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.Request[TResponse](RequestData requestData)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.CallElasticsearch[TResponse](RequestData requestData)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

As I said all the services are working properly and even the Cerebro service is able to connect internally to the elasticsearch service, so it looks like an issue regarding the .net core service only.

I couldn't find any topic regarding the above issue so I hope someone here can help me to figure it out.

PS: the .NET Core API, deployed locally on a Windows machine (Kestrel web server), runs properly connecting to the database and elasticsearch with both of them running on Docker.

**Update:**

I forgot to mention that the machine is running behind a corporate proxy. Keeping that in mind, I wanted to check if my API service was able to reach the Elasticsearch service endpoint: `http://projelastic:9200`.
To do that I executed an interactive bash shell on my API service container:
`docker exec -it proj-core-api /bin/bash`. Here I noticed that my containers do not have access to internet

```
root@8e7c81f98455:/app# apt-get update
Err:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
  Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (111: Connection refused)
```

So I added to the docker-compose file the variables for the proxy server including the no_proxy one for the Elasticsearch service domain.

```
projapi:
    image: proj/projcoreapp 
    depends_on:
       - projmssql
    container_name: proj-core-api
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    restart: always
    #Specify Environment Variables for the Api Service
    environment: 
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Docker
      - http_proxy=http://user:pwd@address      
      - https_proxy=http://user:pwd@address
      - no_proxy=projelastic
```

With the above change I was able to install curl in my API container and perform my initial test:

```
root@0573a44a6836:/app# curl -X GET http://projelastic:9200
{
  "name" : "es01",
  "cluster_name" : "proj-docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "j7mdpxkrSRKxpHnktvnZIw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.10.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "1c34507e66d7db1211f66f3513706fdf548736aa",
    "build_date" : "2020-12-05T01:00:33.671820Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Anyway adding the proxy variables didn't fix the initial error, so as a final test I brought my source code on a `Windows 10 machine` where it's running a `Docker version 20.10.7` and **no proxy**. I built the API image and run the docker-compose. All services work properly, so I still think that on the Linux machine the proxy is playing an important role on my current issue.

**Update 2:**
I was able to fix that issue thanks to the @AndrewSilver suggestion.
Many thanks also to @kha for providing more details.

Comment: You can confirm that In the `*.csproj` you targeting the `net5` framework? Try to change the runtime from `aspnet:5.0` to `aspnet:5.0-focal` maybe on ubuntu there is better compatibility. [See Full Tag Listing](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-runtime/)

Comment: I can confirm that in the the target framework is the following: <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>. I will try to change the runtime in the Docker file and let you know.

Comment: I've just tried with the tag 5.0-focal, but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: You can try to `publish` the .net has a _self-contained_ app and/or for specific RID. Check [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/)

Comment: Can you update the question with the full `.csproj`, maybe the ElasticSearch nuget package has some issue?

Comment: @Max as you suggested I've tried with the following command in the Dockerfile:
`RUN dotnet publish proj.api.net -c Release -o out -r linux-x64 --self-contained true` but I get always the same error.

Comment: There are an update for the [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elasticsearch.Net/) package `Elasticsearch.net 7.14.1`

Comment: @Max The nuget update didn't fix the issue. Anyway I updated my question with additional details.

Comment: You can try adding the proxy on the Windows machine to see if the problem persists, in this case, it is just the proxy. It would be interesting to understand on which line/function of the elasticsearch code the problem occurs, is there more information about it on _stacktrace_?

Comment: @Francesco Did you get anywhere with this? same problem here. Works on Windows but fails on Linux

Comment: are the Linux and Windows 10 machine on the same VLAN?

Comment: Looks like [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/59015) is your issue. The only suggestion I can see is disabling TcpStats if you have it enabled.

Comment: @AndrewSilver Thank you very much! Disabling the TcpStats worked! Perhaps you should add it as answer. The exact command is `connectionSettings.EnableTcpStats(false);`. Remember that TcpStats are enabled if you use DebugMode so make sure to add this as the very last parameter to the connection settings before establishing the connection.

Comment: @Francesco pls write the answer to the question by your self

Comment: @Francesco leave an answer and mark it answer, otherwise, it will be a value-less question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to make sure the above is a useful question, I'm writing here the solution that helped me and others solve the problem and that is to disable **TcpStats**.

@kha also added: The exact command is `connectionSettings.EnableTcpStats(false);`. Remember that TcpStats are enabled if you use DebugMode so make sure to add this as the very last parameter to the connection settings before establishing the connection.